# passing data between activities not working

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have the following scenario in a simple app:
1- the user clicks the menu button on the MainActivity to open another activity on a whole new screen: addTimeActivity, where they can enter a note and its time.
2- The new activity has two edit texts: the time and note, the user enters the data and then clicks save, or they can click the cancel button when they don't want to save the note.
3- the addTimeActiviy passes the data through an intent.
4- the addTimeActivity finishes.
5- The data is supposed to be saved in an adapter which in turn displays it as a list on the MainActivity, the method addTimeRecord in The TimeTrackerAdapter is adding the String data to the times ArrayList.
Now when the save button is clicked, a NullPointerException appears.

Here's the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listView;
TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter;
public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE=1; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    timeTrackerAdapter=new TimeTrackerAdapter();
     listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordList);
    listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_item, menu);
    return true;
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode==TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {   
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String time=extras.getString("time");
        String notes=extras.getString("notes");
        timeTrackerAdapter.addTimeRecord(time, notes);
        timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add_time_menu_item)
   {
       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddTimeActivity.class);
       startActivityForResult(intent,TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);
       return true;
   }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

and here's the addTimeActivity:

```
public class AddTimeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_time);
}
public void onCancel(View view)
{
    finish();
}
public void onSave(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddTimeActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    EditText editTextNotes=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes_edit_text);
    intent.putExtra("notes",editTextNotes.getText().toString());
    EditText editTextTime=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_edit_text);
    intent.putExtra("time", editTextTime.getText().toString());
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
}
```

The adapter:

```
public class TimeTrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

ArrayList<TimeRecord> times=new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();
TextView timeView,noteView;
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return times.size();
}
public TimeTrackerAdapter()
{
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getItem(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return index;
}

public void addTimeRecord(String time,String notes)
{
    TimeRecord timeRecord=new TimeRecord(time,notes);
    times.add(timeRecord);
}
@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(view==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_tracker, parent,false);
    }
    TimeRecord time=times.get(index);
    TextView timeText=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    timeText.setText(time.getTime());
    TextView noteText=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    noteText.setText(time.getNote());
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: check onSave() onCancel() methods in AddTimeActivity. I hope that won't a overridden methods in Activity class

Comment: Can you post your `add_time` code?

Comment: I think you have set the onCancel method to save button click..Please check your xml once

Comment: @Parsad I checked the XML file and it's just fine the onClick attribute are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not initializing your member variable `timeTrackerAdapter`! in your onCreate you do this `TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter=new TimeTrackerAdapter();` but should be `timeTrackerAdapter=new TimeTrackerAdapter();`

also you are using the wrong intent in your onActivityResult. it should be like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) // Intent data is the intent that includes the data of your AddTimeActivity
{
  if(requestCode==TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE)
  {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {   
      Bundle extras=data.getExtras(); // not getIntent().getExtras()
      String time=extras.getString("time");
      String notes=extras.getString("notes");
      timeTrackerAdapter.addTimeRecord(time, notes);
      timeTrackerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I fixed that mistake, and I changed in the addTimeActivity, now the save button is taking me back ti the main activity, but the data is not passed

Comment: are the strings empty/null?

Comment: String time=extras.getString("time");
        String notes=extras.getString("notes");
these two lines are taking the data from the intent before finishing the AddTimeActivity

Comment: i know. and these variables do not contain any data?

Comment: but the values do not get passed back to your main activity? did you debug the code and looked which data the intent includes?

Comment: updated the answer. you were using the wrong intent to get the data!

Comment: but the getextra() method is getting them from the intent, correct me if I'm  wrong? but what's the right way to get the intent?

Comment: yes, but getIntent() gets an intent which has been passed to your main activity when the main activity has been created (not which gets passed onActivityResult). data is the intent which gets passed when you finish the AddTimeActivity (as all the other values in the parameters of the onActivityResult-Method).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, you're the coolest. However, one last thing, now the save button takes back to the MainActivity. However, the data is not there, I have to press the back button which takes me the MainActivity with the data?

Comment: you need to remove the `startActivity(intent);` in your onSave() method. with this you are creating an extra/new  instance of your main activity